# postfix delivery location has changed for new users

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot

I have run my postfix/dovecot server for 6 years with out config change. I have just noticed recently that new users emails are getting delivered to another location.
current users are going to /home/vmail/(email@address)/
new users are going to /home/vmail/(domain)/(user)/
HOWEVER, the checking of all emails are read at /home/vmail/(email@address)/ there for new users are not able to read emails because they are being sent to a difference place.

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
```

/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

```
mail_home = /home/vmail/%u
mail_location = maildir:~
```